# Conditional dynamo global table in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to figure out how to have Global Dynamo table in case a condition a true, otherwise have a regular Dynamo table. However, the linter is complaining about the validity of this: Expected a block but got... at the *Properties*.
Here's my code:

```
Resources:
    ClientNameTable:
      !If
        - SingleEnv
        - Type: AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable
        - Type: AWS::DynamoDB:Table

      Properties:
        TableName: ClientNameTest
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: uuuuu
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: xxxxx
            AttributeType: S
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: uuuuu
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: xxxxx
            KeyType: RANGE
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
        TimeToLiveSpecification:
            AttributeName: time_to_live
            Enabled: true
        Replicas:
          !If
            - SingleEnv
              - Region: us-east-1
              - Region: us-west-2
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put If like that. Instead you have to have **two separate** resources.

```
Resources:
    ClientNameTable:
      Condition: SingleEnv  
      Properties:
        TableName: ClientNameTest
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: uuuuu
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: xxxxx
            AttributeType: S
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: uuuuu
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: xxxxx
            KeyType: RANGE
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
        TimeToLiveSpecification:
            AttributeName: time_to_live
            Enabled: true
        Replicas:
          !If
            - SingleEnv
              - Region: us-east-1
              - Region: us-west-2
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
            
            
    ClientNameTable:
      Condition: NotSingleEnv  
      Properties:
        TableName: ClientNameTest
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: uuuuu
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: xxxxx
            AttributeType: S
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: uuuuu
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: xxxxx
            KeyType: RANGE
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
        TimeToLiveSpecification:
            AttributeName: time_to_live
            Enabled: true
        Replicas:
          !If
            - SingleEnv
              - Region: us-east-1
              - Region: us-west-2
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Where `NotSingleEnv` you have to create in `Conditions`.

Comment: But that means I'd have to create a new table. My only purpose here was to not have to migrate data into the new table but reuse the existing one.

Comment: @elena Not sure what do you mean. Anyway, you can't do what you want to do with your If statement.

Comment: what I am trying to say is that I want to create a global table from the local table. Depending on the environment, it would either be a global table or a local table. And I don't want to create a new table, I want to reuse the old one for the global table. But that's impossible, isn't it?

Comment: @elena Not sure do you mean by "reuse"? You want to reuse the source code?

Comment: Btw, your example has !If statement just like what I created in my own example.

Comment: I want to reuse the table, meaning to have the same table as before with the same data in it. It's thousands of rows.

Comment: @elena I mean the first If statement of yours. In my answer it is `Condition: SingleEnv`.

Comment: What about the second !If? Linter still complains about it.

Comment: @elena Second one is OK. Sadly, linters for CFN are usually useless. Just test your code on a **dummy** table with some test data to ensure it works (or does not work) as expected.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I wondered if there's a way to set the Type with !If?

Comment: @elena Sadly without a macro, you can't modify type the way you want.

Comment: what's a macro?

Comment: @elena https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html